# HQL - getResultSet using proxy

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to execute this command :

```
Query q = sql.get().createQuery("SELECT object(p) from Participation p where p.member.address = :address").setParameter("address", address);

List<Participation> participations = q.getResultList();
```

When I debug the function, the 'getResultList()' passes by this function (from the package org.hibernate.engine.internal;)

```
public Object proxyFor(EntityPersister persister, EntityKey key, Object impl) throws HibernateException {
    if(!persister.hasProxy()) {
        return impl;
    } else {
        Object proxy = this.proxiesByKey.get(key);
        return proxy != null?this.narrowProxy(proxy, persister, key, impl):impl;
        }
    }
```

How may I force the no use of proxy via a HQL command ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 'q.list()' method for getting the result as a list.

Query class does not have any method with getResultSet() name.

**Check query class documentation**
[click here!!!](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html)